# Unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linker, unresolved-external

Help me guys,
I've been searching for a really long time.

I'm using visual studio 2010 and I tried to include an external lib but I get an unresolved external error.

The external project is composed of files in the following way

```
backend.cpp
//some functions 
frontend.cpp
//some functions
header.h
```

I build this project using SCons then I includes the .lib file in the project and refered to its path and I copied the .h file to msvc directory .

VS seems to access and read the functions in backend.cpp(from the auto complete) but when I run the project it says that there is an unresolved external @ the called function

Comment: Did you add the `lib` to the `Additional libraries` section of your project settings?

Comment: I added it to the additional dependencies

Comment: The exact error message would be helpful, also the *complete* function declaration of the function the linker is missing.

Comment: @Doc I wrote the error message on rodrigo's answer

Comment: @Poka Yoke: and where is the *complete* function declaration?

Comment: @Doc I didn't write it because I tried it with a different function and still the same error for the other function, so I think the declaration is not the source of error .. What do you think?

Comment: @Doc I tried even calling another function that is not part of the struct and still I get an unresolved external !!!

Comment: @Poka: seems the compiler does not generate the same symbols for the functions of your lib when the header files are compiled, either for the lib or for the project using the lib. Might be a preprocessor problem (different symbols defined), impossible for me to say without seeing the source. Do you use exactly the same runtime libs for your lib and the project using the lib?

Comment: I can't really understand the question but I would like to point out something that may be of help. I build the backend/frontend by an external building tool SCons which generates the .lib file and I try to include it in VS, can this be a source of error? regarding the source code i just wrote a function that prints out "test" and is not part of any struct and still I have the same problem ! By the way shall I add the header/cpp to the project or stating the directory is enough?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Visual Studio expert, but I guess that it being able to auto complete your code is associated with it finding the headers of your source code.

Unresolved external means that the compiler can't find the object files in the linking process. This could mean that you failed to add the lib files correctly, or that you are missing some .cpp file.

Comment: shall I add the .cpp files to th he project or the lib and .h files are enough especially that the .h interfaces both the backend and the frontend files

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to add the .cpp files. All you should have to do is add the .lib file to the `Additional Dependencies`, which you say you already did.  Did you do that for `All Configurations`?

Comment: I meant that you could be missing some .cpp file because you didn't provide the complete error message. Maybe it is another file that doesn't even have anything to do with the library, although I don't think that this is the case.

Comment: Is this "void_thiscall IStruct::init(void)" function part of the library or part of your backend/frontend software?

Comment: "Compiler can't find the object files in linking process" - It is either the compiler or the linker. And the unresolved error is raised by linker only.

Answer (score 1):

That may happen for a variety of reasons. But all of them end up being one of the following:

- You are not linking the correct .lib file.
- The symbol name you are using in your program is not identical to the one provided in the .lib.

The first one is easy enough to check, so please, double check it.

The second one is trickier. The symbol name used in your program is output in the error message "unresolved external symbol **abc**", or whatever. The symbols available in the library can be listed with the command: `dumpbin /all name.lib`.

If you cannot find the problem, please post the exact error you are getting and the output of the dumpbin program.

Comment: error LINK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:void_thiscall IStruct::init(void)" (?init@IStruct@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "private:void _thiscall Main::on_donebutton_clicked(void)"(?on_donebutton_clicked@Main@@AAEXXZ).

Comment: I opened the vs command line then I navigated to the directory of the .lib file then I typed the command you gave me and the output is a description of how the lib is stored

Comment: If the `dump /all` command doesn't report any symbol, chances are that your library is not built properly. You should try building it manually instead of with scons.

Comment: Actually dump /all showed a lot of data how can I know that the .lib is built correctly?

Comment: You should look for section "public symbols" and see if you can find your funcion there. Or else in "COFF SYMBOL TABLE" an external symbol with that same name. If you cannot find them try the `dumpbin /archivemembers name.lib` command. It should list the name of the *.obj files in the library. If you cannot find the `backend.obj` and `frontend.obj` names in there... well, then they are not there.

Comment: Use Dependency Walker (www.dependencywalker.com )for your DLL and see it that symbols actually exists (Click on C++ button and see undecorated name to see if symbols matches correctly). Are you sure the class/struct is exported from DLL?

Comment: @rodrigo no they are not there ! what shall I do then?

Comment: @Ajay the project that I want to include has only a .lib file

Comment: @Poka Yoke: You mean a static library?

Comment: Just to make sure, what exactly should I do so that I can include a header file in the project?